# Sending text from QTextEdit to QListWidget on pushing QPushButton - Qt

Tags: c++, qt, signals, signals-slots

So, I have the following design:

**List box

Text box

Push button**

When I push the button, the text from the text box should go to the list box.

QTextEdit has the following signal:
`void QTextEdit::textChanged () [signal]`

But, doesn't this mean that when user presses an alphabet, a signal will be sent? But, I want the whole paragraph to go to the list box (at once) on the push of the button.

Should I send the data from text box to button and then from button to list box? Or there another way out?

### EDIT 1:

I have been successful in sending the text from list box to the button, but how to send the text from button to list box?

**Button has no signal which sends the text.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should handle QPushButtons's **clicked** signal and then in that signal you can get QTextEdit's text content by **toPlainText** () API and you can insert this to List box's model

Comment: `you can insert this to List box's model` How to insert the text from button to list box? Button has no signal which sends the text.

Comment: Well, I made my own signal. :)